# How to put content evenly by vertical in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to put content items evenly by vertical in LinearLayout on my Android screen, but items cuddle to top. How to fix it?
Here is my screen in xml-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/olumn128"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />    
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First is that you don't need nested `LinearLayout` to achieve what you want. So you can remove your second `LinearLayout`.

To make views occupy height of screen evenly, you can use `android:layout_weight="1"` then set your `android:layout_height="0dp"`. Set those attributes to the views you want to have equal height.

Also, remove your `weightSum` in the `LinearLayout`, because by setting the `layout_weight` of your views equal to 1, you are implicitly telling that the `weightSum` is 2 and that your views are sharing it equally.